# and choose a directory back htacces

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

my home directory is this **/public_html/**

my subdomain directory is  **/public_html/es/**

what I need is my subdomain to point to the main directory. using htacces
    I am using  ../ but does not work :(

I imagine that this can do, and if it is not possible please tell me

```
# Activar RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.example\.me$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^../index.php
RewriteRule (.*) ../index.php$1 [L]
```

Comment: How was your subdomain created? Are you using cPanel? You need to change the document root for your subdomain to point to the main domain's document root (your main directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is all that is needed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.example\.me$
RewriteRule es/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```